# Enable refresh edmx or update model from database during build

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, continuous-integration, edmx

I have MVC 5 web application project where i have *.edmx file. which i refresh using the wizard by right click on file and select update model from database and then select refresh and finish. 
How do i achieve this which taking a build?

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh your model from the database locally and then commit the changes generated by this refresh to source control, your edmx will be up to date the next time you run a build. Refreshing the model from database just updates files within the edmx. This is no different than manually editing any other file in your project.